# VB script to find whether it is running in 32 bit or 64 bit

Tags: vbscript, wsh

how to find which command prompt(32 bit or 64) is being used to run the vb script when it is called using cscript. I need to capture that info.

Comment: [WMIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wmic) gives you a lot of information about *everything* (almost). See the `OS` option (e.g., `wmic os get /?` in the command line to show available properties). Don't use `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`.

Comment: I found a way to get the details, the following command give us the details                                                                                                             C:\>tasklist /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /v /fo List

Image Name:   cmd.exe
PID:          10088
Session Name: RDP-Tcp#5
Session#:     2
Mem Usage:    13,556 K
Status:       Running
User Name:    SPG069\Administrator
CPU Time:     0:00:00
Window Title: Administrator: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe - tasklist  /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /v /fo List